# Django Rest Framework get login method used

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-auth

I'm using Django Rest Framework with [django-oauth-toolkit](https://github.com/evonove/django-oauth-toolkit) for oauth2 and [django-rest-auth](https://github.com/Tivix/django-rest-auth) for social login, and I need to know how a user logged in, so I can manage password change for instance.

Until now, the only way I found is getting `request.auth._meta.app_label`, which will be `'oauth2_provider'` for oauth login or `'authtoken'` for Facebook login, as the latter uses a normal DRF token, but I think this isn't specific enough.

Is there a way of knowing exactly how a user logged in?